# Downloading videos using iTunes, how can I back them up?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I subscribed to these podcasts which are actually vidoes.

I can see that iTunes downloads them locally to my computer, but I am not sure of the location of where they are downloaded.

I want to transfer them to a CD or my other computer, how can I do this?
Will iTunes possibly delete these after a while if I don't view them?

Answer (score 1):

By default the files iTunes uses are located in :

```
~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music
```

iTunes does not delete podcast files by it self. You have to do it manually.